# Creating Trigger to update table with change of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

I have a database with two tables. They are,

order(userid,name,index,total)

```
userid | total

sandun | 2500
sandun | 4800
akmal  | 1200
```

paynow(userid,totalpayment)

```
userid  | totalpayment
sandun  | 14000
akmal   | 22500
```

I need to update paynow table when the insertion in orders table corresponding userid. So I made a trigger for that. It is here,

```
CREATE TRIGGER totals
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
WHEN(NEW.userid IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE paynow
SET totalpayment = totalpayment + NEW.total
WHERE userid = NEW.userid
END;
```

But it is giving this error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN(NEW.userid IS NOT NULL)
>   UPDATE paynow
>   SET totalpayment = totalpayment + N' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQL` triggers don't have a `when` clause. You can use an `if` statement instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totals
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.userid IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE paynow
    SET totalpayment = totalpayment + NEW.total
    WHERE userid = NEW.userid;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `when` clause is superfluous to the query.  You *could* just leave it out:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totals
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE paynow
        SET totalpayment = totalpayment + NEW.total
        WHERE userid = NEW.userid;
END;
```

If `NEW.userid` is `NULL`, then no rows will be updated.  Assuming you have an index on `paynow(userid)` (which I strongly, strongly recommend), then there isn't that much of a performance penalty either.

Also, do you care if `NEW.total` could be `NULL`?  I might expect:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER totals
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE paynow
        SET totalpayment = totalpayment + NEW.total
        WHERE userid = NEW.userid AND NEW.total IS NOT NULL;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: now it shows this error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj . . . You probably need `DELIMITER` statements.